# \033 Prompt in unix

Tags: c, unix, signals, terminal-emulator

I wrote a signal handler that prints a line from buffer, it first removes the previous prompt, print a line and prints the prompt again at the end of the screen. here is my handler.

```
void print(int param)
{
  int c;
  signal(SIGALRM, print);
  printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\033[0K");
  print_line();
  printf("\033[7m--HEY--\033[0m");
}
```

This handler is doing everything I wanted except that I could not see the prompt at the end of the screen. I do not understand why I am not able to see the prompt that?

Comment: You have `null` escape sequences in what you are printing. Why?

Comment: Because I am printing a prompt before entering this loop so I want to delete that first and print that again after printing the line.

Comment: `\b` is the backspace escape. I'm talking about where you have `\0`. I'm pretty sure that winds up being a `null` byte. Unless the compiler interprets that as an octal escape sequence `\033`.

Comment: @EricUrban It is indeed an octal escape sequence.

Comment: Strictly, you should not use `printf()` (or `fflush()`) from a signal handler (but `write()` would be OK).

Comment: @sepp2k Ah, ok. I've never understood the need to use octal. But that's good to know. I prefer the hexadecimal escapes like `'\x00'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard output is usually line buffered. End with a `\n` character, or flush explicitly like this:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: I would use fflush(stdout) to avoid changing the behavior.